# Are there any tools/ python packages for Fuzzy Grouping?

Tags: python, fuzzy-logic

I'm trying to get to a tool for Fuzzy Grouping as I do not have a reference column for matching the string. Is there any package on Python or R? 
I looked at a package called textpack but the results aren't good.

found here:
https://pypi.org/project/textpack/

I'd really appreciate if someone could suggest a tool or a package so I can go ahead and research.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/13636848/745868

Comment: Isn't that fuzzy matching? I'm trying to get fuzzy grouping done since I don't have a reference column

Comment: I expanded my comment into an answer

Answer (score 1):

Probably there are more direct solutions, but you can try using some sort of [fuzzy matching](http://fuzzy%20matching) to get the most similar words to each word. That returns you an unweighted graph where the nodes are words and the edge indicates whether the world is similar. then, you can try clustering the resulting graph, for example with the [Louvain's algorithm](https://thisarticledoesnotexist.com/). Than would return non overlapping groups of related words.